# Adding a link/website to a button using props

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get a button to link to a website using react.js but I can't seem to figure out how to get it working. From the code below everything works perfectly except for the button (props.website). Nothing happens when I click the button. What am I doing wrong?

```
   function Card(props){
    return(
        <MDBCol>
<MDBCard style={{ width: "22rem" }}>
  <MDBCardImage className="img-fluid" src={props.image} waves />
  <MDBCardBody>
    <MDBCardTitle>{props.name}</MDBCardTitle>
    <MDBCardText>
    {props.meaning}
    </MDBCardText>
    <MDBBtn href={props.website} >View Project</MDBBtn>
  </MDBCardBody>
</MDBCard>
</MDBCol> 
    );
}
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a mroe semantically correct anchor tag? What is `MDBBtn`? Can you provide that component code?

Comment: Looks like it matches [the examples](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/components/buttons/#buttons-links).  Are there any errors in the browser console?  What is the resulting markup on the page for the button?  When you debug this, what do you verify `props.website` to contain?

Comment: @David No, there does not appear to be any errors in the console. My bad, I mentioned before that nothing happens when clicking on the button, but actually when I do click on the button it directs to http://localhost:3000/www.google.com (where I have google.com as an example under the element in my array) But Ideally I just want it to direct to www.google.com not http://localhost:3000/www.google.com

Comment: @DrewReese I tried also with just a regular button tag as well but the same outcome occurs.

Comment: What is the value of `props.website` you are trying to use? Is it a fully qualified web address? Seems you are trying to navigate to "www.google.com" versus "http://www.google.com" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment on the question above:

> it directs to localhost:3000/www.google.com

Then the link is actually working.  But the URL is wrong.  You appear to be using this URL:

```
'www.google.com'
```

But a browser has no way of knowing that this is another website.  Structurally it's no different than, say, this:

```
'www.index.html'
```

Which is a perfectly valid name for a resource on your website.

To tell the browser that this should go to another website, include the protocol:

```
'http://www.google.com'
```

Or at least the `//` at the start to default to whatever the current page's protocol is:

```
'//www.google.com'
```

Comment: Ah no way such an easy fix! I apologize, I am pretty new to all of this... I just fixed it and all is well. Good to know for the future. Thank you so much!